# Iterating cookies in Play+Java

Tags: java, cookies, playframework-2.0

I've been looking into managing the cookies stored by a play application.  Ideally I'd like to iterate all of the cookies for that user and selectively remove some based on some conditions.  Before I do that, though, I wanted to simply iterate the cookies to view them, such as:

```
for (Http.Cookie cookie : Http.Context.current().response().cookies()) {
    Logger.info("cookie " + cookie.name());
}
```

Even though we use cookies productively in many other places in the application, cookies() comes up with nothing.  If I look at cookies().size, it's 0.  I have the web inspector open showing about 15-20 cookies available. Am I using the wrong command?

I investigated this further and sometimes I get a few cookies, but never more than 1 or 2 of the 20-ish visible in web inspector.  I am able to verify that those cookies are being read elsewhere.  I can even .get(name) specific cookies that don't show up in the iterator.

Comment: Which version of Play 2 exactly?

Comment: Using play version 2.3.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reading cookies from the response, not the request.  The response will only show cookies that you've set in the current request, since cookies are only sent in a response when you set them.  If you want to see all the incoming cookies, you need to iterate over the cookies from the request:

```
for (Http.Cookie cookie : Http.Context.current().request().cookies()) {
    Logger.info("cookie " + cookie.name());
}
```